# Why datamapper does not update records / detect dirtiness?

Tags: ruby, database, migration, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I recently wanted to write a simple migration script. I wrote:

```
@entries = Entries.all(:text => /test/)

@entries.each do |entry|
  entry.update(:text => entry.text.gsub!(/test/, "no-test"))
end
```

It didn't save the records, even though the update statement returned true. What did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 1.x series of datamapper the dirty tracking is done via calling `#==` on the new and old attribute values to detect dirtyness. If an object is mutated inplace (for example with the String bang methods), the change cannot be detected as the "orignal" state gets mutated also.

Basically the following happens internally:

```
a = "foo"
b = a.gsub!("foo", "bar")
a == b     # => true both a and b refer to the same mutated object
a.equal?(b) # => true
```

In your example you assign the original mutated attribute back to the object, no identity change => no update detected.

In case you create a new object via `String#gsub` istead of mutating the original attribute value via `String#gsub!` you end up with a detectable change.

With assigning a new object with different value the following happens:

```
a = "foo"
b = a.gsub("foo", "bar")
a == b      # => false, loaded state does not equal resource state so change is detected
a.equal?(b) # => false
```

And for having all cases covered, assigning a new object with same value:

```
a = "foo"
b = "foo"
a == b      # => true, no dirtyness detected.
a.equal?(b) # => false
```

Hopefully this explains the semantic differences good enough to explain all similar cases.

BTW In datamapper 2.0 we have a differend mechanism that will also catch in place mutations. Disclaimer, I'm the author of this component called [dm-session](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-session).

Comment: Aah! using Equals to detect deltas for updates - I was going crazy trying to find the right 'search keywords' to understand how a data mapper figures out the exact set of records to write out in a Master-Detail kind of domain object. Using enums {added/deleted/updated} or dirty flags didn't seem right. If you have any resources in this area, please do share - Thanks!

Comment: Enums are represented as bitmaps to Fixnums internally. Fixnums cannot be mutated in-place in ruby so this is not a problem.

Assuming you are talking about enums from dm-types gem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the exclamation.

`entry.update(:text => entry.text.gsub(/test/, "no-test"))`

The record doesn't go dirty when you replace the string content. You should reassign it.

Comment: thank you, now I do understand why `!` stands for `dangerous` ;)